# SignalR Core not using Websockets in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working on a SignalR Core web app that uses the following stack:

- ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview 2 (2.1.0-preview2-final)
- SignalR Core 1.0 preview 2 (1.0.0-preview2-final)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors (2.1.0-preview2-final)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets (2.1.0-preview2-final)

The client is using SignalR NPM package (@aspnet/signalr).

The app is configured like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ClientHub>("/hubs/notifications");
    });
}
```

When running locally in `http://localhost`, the client connects using WS protocol. But when deployed in Azure App Service, it falls back to SSE.

The browser log shows:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/hubs/notifications?id=ZRniWKpMLMPIyLhS5RSyAg' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
Information: SSE connected to https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/hubs/notifications?id=ig47oOdQzbasdgrlr0cHaw
```

The `negotiate` method seems to return support to Websockets:

```
{"connectionId":"ZRniWKpMLMPIyLhS5RSyAg",
 "availableTransports":[
  {"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},
  {"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},
  {"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is WSS not yet supported?

Comment: Did you enable WS on the Azure App Service instance?

Comment: /facepalm I failed to see there was a setting to do that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer my own question, the failure in the Websocket connection was not a problem with ASP.NET Core or the stack, but due to the fact that Azure App Service needs to have Websockets enabled in the **Application Settings**:

[image: WebSocket switch in Application Settings]

Comment: I don't see that setting on my web app, I only see Always On, any other settings to enable to get this?

Comment: They are still there, obviously more than a year passed since this answer and UIs are bound to change. Settings > Configuration and then, in the General settings tab. It could be a limitation of your App Service pricing tier?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the replay and meant to update this. I did a little research and turns out the feature is not currently available for Linux Host but you can enable ARR Affinity with always on to achieve similar behavior. I do agree that the original is old, and the intention was to try to find if I was missing smething.

Comment: Hi,  have a question. Deployed the asp.net web api with socket. its working in local after hosted in azure its not working. we have enabled the websocket in Azure App service. but not getting connect. Its should error while establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 answer.

To enable Web Sockets on a modern console go to `Home -> App Services -> your_app_name -> (Settings) Configuration -> General Settings` and set `Web sockets` property to `On`.
[image]

Comment: This setting is gone in 2024?