# How to create a connectable websocket server on Azure app services?

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, cloud

I'm currently running a node and websocket server on azure app services, server looks like this

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require("express")();
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const path = require('path')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
const url = require('url');

const httpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
    res.end("Hello");
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log("Listening.. on 80"));
const websocketServer = require("websocket").server

const wsServer = new websocketServer({
    "httpServer": httpServer
})
wsServer.on("request", request => {
    //connect

    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    connection.on("open", () => console.log("opened!"))
    connection.on("close", () => console.log("closed!"))
    connection.on("message", message => {
        const result = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data)

    })

    var payLoad = {
        "method": "connect",
        "thing": "TEST"
    }

    connection.send(JSON.stringify(payLoad));
})
```

However anytime I try to connect I get 
`(index):79 WebSocket connection to 'ws://triverserver-50.azurewebsites.net/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

I saw that docker was started on port 8080 in the logs and have tried adding `WEBSITES_PORT:80` and `PORT:80` to general settings but they had no effect. Any Ideas?

Comment: have you checked if WebSockets is enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821363/1384539

Comment: Yeah, It is enabled.